# Heroku error code H10 when Spring Boot app is deployed

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I can't open my app in Heroku - I get error H10. When I run my app in Eclipse or use executable jar file - everything work well. Here is my code : [GITHub](https://github.com/Marcin1112/spring_boot_page.git) Below is my log file:
[DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xcsskwler46izt/log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: How are you deploying? With `git push` or `heroku jar:deploy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You app is running on port 8080, but on Heroku it needs to bind to the environment variable `$PORT`. You can fix Spring to do this by adding the following to your `application.properties`:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

This will use `$PORT` if it's set, and default to 8080 if it's not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise. When I added 'server.port=${PORT:8080}' everything work well

Comment: Hello. Would you be so kind to take a look at my question on Heroku? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725299/heroku-the-simplest-application-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-web-some. No one else seems to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error using Procfile, the Procfile is always a simple text file that is named Procfile without a file extension, For example, Procfile.txt is not valid, The Procfile must live in your app’s root directory. It does not function if placed anywhere else.

**What to write in Procfile?**

```
  web: java -jar build/libs/your-project-name-version.jar
```

the version you can find inside build.gradle/pom.xml

Example:-      `web: java -jar build/libs/khatabook-1.0.jar`

**Where to create Procfile?**

I have given my project structure image link for
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsB35.png

My gradle file link
https://github.com/himanshujainpro/khatabook/blob/master/build.gradle

My application.properties
https://github.com/himanshujainpro/khatabook/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Project link for further reference
https://github.com/himanshujainpro/khatabook